# Error in printing message to LCD via Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, lcd

```
from RPLCD import CharLCD
lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23])
lcd.write_string('Hello world!')
```

I've wired my raspberry pi and LCD exactly as the picture below and here's my code, however nothing is printing. I'm getting this error /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/RPLCD/gpio.py:149: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

[image]

Comment: Try using the correct BCM PIN numbers

Comment: @Milliways Im confused, did I not put the pins in the correct place?

Comment: You have used physical pin numbers - most code uses BCM pin numbers.

Comment: Do you know about the site pinout.zyx from Pimoroni?  This shows you both the board numbers (shown on the Pi board by the pins) and the BCM numbers - this lets you select the correct pin number for the library.